# GUI frozen while waiting on an answer from the client

Tags: java

I'm currently having some issues running this small battleship program I am working on. I have two GUI, one for the server and one for the client. When I click the "Start Server" jButton, the program will freeze until it receives something from the client side.

Image of the GUI if it helps:

[image: GUI]

I have no issues unfreezing it by starting the client program, my issue is, how can I make it so that it just doesn't freeze while waiting? thanks a lot.

```java
package battleship;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author ftonye
 */
public class BackGroundCom implements Runnable {

    private int port;
    private ServerSocket ss;
    private Socket cs;
    private Scanner reader;
    private PrintStream writer;
    public int missileIncomming;
    public int missileOutgoing;
    public Boolean dataToSend;
    InetAddress sa = null;

    public BackGroundCom(int port) {
        this.port = port;
        dataToSend = true;
        missileOutgoing = 100;

        startServer();
    }

    private void startServer() {
        try {
            sa = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            System.out.println(sa);
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BackGroundCom.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        System.out.println("Server started");

        try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(this.port);
            cs = ss.accept();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Server accept connection from" + cs.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
        }

        System.out.println("Server accept connection");

    }
```

Part of my BattleSea.java, which is where I click the button before it freezes:

```java
btnStartServer = new JButton("Start Server");
        btnStartServer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                com = new BackGroundCom(Integer.parseInt(txtPortNumber.getText().toString()));
                t = new Thread(com);
                t.start();


            }

        });
```

I am trying to understand how to get it to never freeze. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect that it is the call `cs = ss.accept();` that is blocking. This is going to block until the client connects to the server.  You run this in response to pushing the button, because in your button action code, you construct a `BackGroundCom`, and that object's constructor calls `startServer`, which executes this `accept()` line directly.

It seems like you are trying to set up the `BackGroundCom` object so that what it does occurs in a background thread, but what I describe above all happens before you create and run the thread.  Maybe what you want to do is move the `startServer` call into the `run()` method of the `BackGroundCom` object.  I don't see a `run()` method in `BackGroundCom`, although it implements `Runnable`.  I assume it's further down in the code.  Without it, this code wouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

[Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7631480/steve) is right. `ServerSocket.accept();` method will block until a connection is made. You have to put it inside another `Thread` so it won't block the `EDT(Event Dispatching Thread)`. EDT is where your GUI runs.

```
public BackGroundCom(int port) {
    this.port = port;
    dataToSend = true;
    missileOutgoing = 100;

    new Thread(() -> (startServer()).start(); // run in new thread
}
```

Comment: you probably missed it, but he already has logic for starting a thread and providing his BackGroundCom object as the Runnable for the thread.  So he's presumably already got a run() method being called by a background thread in his BackGroundCom object, and just needs to move startServer() into that method...a 1 line change potentially.

Comment: You are right again! It is indeed a one line change. He just needs to rename his `startServer()` method to `run()`, or use my approach. Both will work.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right - well, and he has to take the call out of his constructor.